# Tweeting to someone on NCIS without letting other people know my real name

Tags: twitter

How would I let people from the TV series *NCIS* know that I enjoy the program, but at the same time not let on to other people on Twitter know who I am or what my real name is?

I want to be able to tweet an *NCIS* actor but not have other people know my identity.

Answer (score 1):

Create an anonymous account. Unless one of the actors or producers are following; in that case you could just DM one of them from your primary account.